# Jquery cycle audio

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin for an app I'm writing, and it works fine using images.  e.g.

```
<img src="file1.jpg">
<img src="file2.jpg">
...etc
```

However, I would like to use the plugin with sound clips rather than images, and although the cycle website says "slideshows are not limited to images. You can use any element you want." simply replacing the img tags with audio tags doesn't work.  What happens is that with autoplay on all the clips play at once, and with autoplay off, none of the clips play.
What I effectively want to do is to have a sound 'slideshow' rather than an image slideshow. 
I have googled this extensively, but have found no solutions using the cycle plugin. Could anyone point me inn the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily write your own by attaching to the events raised by the HTML5 `audio` element. Try this:

```
<div class="audio-container">
    <audio src="file1.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <audio src="file2.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <!-- more audio elements as needed... -->
</div>
```

```js
$('.audio-container audio').on('ended', function() {
    var $nextAudio = $(this).next('audio');
    if ($nextAudio.length) 
        $nextAudio[0].play();
});

$('.audio-container audio:first')[0].play();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.  My JS isn't very strong as I write mainly server code, so learning how to do this is really interesting.